# ¿Cómo agregar evento de cambio de valor a un combobox generado dinamicamente en un table?

Tags: jquery, combobox

Generé un `combobox` dinámicamente mediante el siguiente código

```
fila+=
'<td id="adul"><select name="cliente" class="populate select2-offscreen selectclient" style="width: 100%" tabindex="-1" onchange="changeAction()"  id="adul'+ types[i][j].numhabitacion +'">',
```

Sin embargo, cuando intento extraer el id me muestra `undefined`.

```
function changeAction()
  { 
      var z=$(this).attr('id')
      alert(z);       
  }
```

¿Qué me sugieren al respecto?. Saludos...

Answer (score 0):

Para ésto no necesitas jQuery, ya que puedes acceder al `id` de manera directa vía la propiedad.

Tienes dos opciones:

- Pasarle `this` como parámetro
- Pasarle `event` como parámetro

Pasando `this` como sugiere @aldanux, estás pasando el elemento mismo (select), por ende, tienes acceso a todos las propiedades y funciones de éste, entre ellos, `id`.

```js
function onChange (select) {
   console.log(select.id); 
}
```

```html
<select id="adul" onchange="onChange(this)">
  <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

Si pasas `event` estás pasando el [evento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) que se ha disparado en el cambio de selección. Útil si quieres accederl evento, prevenir la propagación del mismo, etc.

```js
function onChange (ev) {
   console.log(ev.target.id); 
}
```

```html
<select id="adul" onchange="onChange(event)">
  <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Estas obteniendo el `id` del `select` en lugar del `td`:

Intenta esto:

```
function changeAction()
{ 
   var z = $(this).parent().attr('id');
   alert(z); 
}
```

Así obtendrás el `id` del `td`.

Ejemplo trabajando:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  alert("idparent: " + $(this).parent().attr('id') + ", Select value" + this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Combo</th>
      <th>d1</th>
      <th>d2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="adul1">
        <select>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>dd</td>
      <td>ss</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="adul2">
        <select>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>

      </td>
      <td>aa</td>
      <td>qq</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Solo recuerda que el `id` debe ser único al momento de generarlo dinamicamente.

Comment: Si uso var z= $(this).parent().attr('id'); cuando le hago un alert me muestra undefined y si tiene id. Ya pude obtener el id del combobox, pero no el de su padre(el id del td). Como podria hacer?

Comment: @lucho edité mi respuesta